# Microsoft Graph Automation Powershell Script

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to schedule a powershell script to run which will export some Graph API data into some CSV files. I have a script that works, however, it requires you to copy and paste a device code every time you run a script.

The script need to run with delegated permissions as the call does not support application permissions.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: What is your requirement here?

Comment: I want to automate Graph API calls with delegated permissions. I have tried previously with power automate but this has limitations. I don't mind what I use really, I have just found Powershell easiest to use so far.

Comment: You can get started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/get-started). For your scenario you can use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to Authenticate.

Comment: Moving this to answer. If my answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking the check mark so that it could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can get started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/get-started).For your scenario you can use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to Authenticate. And also remember that the ROPC flow is not recommended by Microsoft.